# How to show progress based on the number of processed items instead of the number of their "costs" with "ruby-progressbar"?

Tags: ruby, iteration, progress-bar, progress

Let's initialize an array with random numbers.
Now let's create a `ProgressBar` with the sum of all numbers as its size.
We can easily iterate through all numbers and increment the progress bar with each number, which gives us a very neat and precise progressing:

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'

items = Array.new(100) { rand 1..10 }

progress_bar = ProgressBar.create total: items.sum, format: '%a %e %P% Processed: %c from %C items'

items.each do |item|
  sleep item / 100.0
  progress_bar.progress += item
end
```

However, the user is interested to see how many of the items are processed while the progress is ongoing and not the weighted costs of the items. Now we show for instance `Processed: 270 from 516 items` which is the sum of the already processed items versus the total sum. Instead, I want to show `Processed: 53 from 100 items`, but leave behind the scenes the total sum and the incrementing to be as they are now, as otherwise the progress bar will not be accurate.

`ruby-progressbar` offers [the following flags for formatting](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar/wiki/Formatting).

I do not see any options for putting placeholders or for deriving values in it.

Comment: So you want to show the progress bar the weighted sum but the text should show the number of jobs that have been processed?

Comment: Exactly, this is the idea :) We can achieve accurate progressing only by using the weighted sum as the jobs have different weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [customize format string in realtime while processing](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar/wiki/Realtime-Customization) and update values yourself inside the format string. Below is the modified script to show you what I mean:

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'

items = Array.new(100) { rand 1..10 }
current = 0
count = items.count
progress_bar = ProgressBar.create total: items.sum, format: "%a %e %P% Processed: #{current} from #{count} items"

items.each do |item|
  sleep item / 100.0
  current += 1
  progress_bar.format = "%a %e %P% Processed: #{current} from #{count} items"
  progress_bar.progress += item
end
```

Sample output: `Time: 00:00:01  ETA: 00:00:04 29.48% Processed: 27 from 100 items`